# How to tell whether you've found the minimum number sent to the first that also maximizes the candy sent to the first person?

Tags: optimization

> 16 children are standing in line to receive a total of $100$ pieces of candy, with each child guaranteed to receive at least $1$ piece. At (leas) how many pieces must the first child in line receive to ensure that he or she has the greatest number after all 100 pieces are distributed?

I am not sure how to determine what the absolute minimum the first receives is.

If the first child receives $9$, $14$ of the children can receive $6$ each, and the last child receives seven.

How do I know whether I reached the bottom?

a is number first person receives, b is number 15-n receives, n receives q each.

[image]

Comment: Well, if the first child received $>50$ candies they would be sure to have the max, right?  What about $40$?  Is that good enough?  Write down the constraints and the answer should drop out.

Comment: Post edit:  I think you are over complicating this.  There's no need for a computer program...you can do this mentally.  For instance: $45$ is good enough since, if someone else had $46$ then that would account for $91$ candies, leaving at most $9$...not enough to give everyone else one.  And so on.

Comment: One way to look at it might be to consider just how many 'extra' candies each child gets. In that case there's 100-16=84 'extra' candies in supply, and none of the children (after the first) have to get a candy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the boundary, all but two people receive one candy each.  This leaves $86$ candies.  This means that if one of the people receives exactly $43$ candies, that might not be sufficient, because another person might also receive $43$ candies.

$44$ candies is sufficient, because $14$ of the remaining $15$ must receive **at least** one candy each, leaving only $42$ remaining for the last person.

Comment: ... Why not If the first child receives 9
, 14
 of the children other than the first can receive 6
 each, and the last child receives seven.

Comment: @user1109365 Reread the posted problem.  If the first child receives $9$, that doesn't **guarantee** that the first child will have the most, because the second child might also receive (at least) $9$.  If the first child receives $44$, this does guarantee that the first child gets more than everyone else.  If the first child gets only $43$, the second child might also get $43.$

Comment: the children can't get in line again. 9, 6,6,....,7.

Comment: @user1109365 The way that I read the posted problem, the problem is asking for the minimum number that must be given to the first child to **guarantee** that no other child is given as much.  Giving the first child $9$ will work with some distributions to the other $15$ children, but will not work for **every** possible distribution to the other $15$ children.  I don't understand your reference to *getting in line again*.